# JS Change function working only first time

Tags: javascript, html, function

In this, I have a give module (wordpress plugin for fundraiser) and I have integrated the file upload

https://www.mamafrica.it/26964-2/

I have add a java script in order to check the file size and file type, but this work only until I not change the payment method.

For example: 
After load page, if I load file > 500KB or different from pdf or jpg, error message appears under the file upload area.
If I switch to "Donation by bank transfer" the form change (an information text appears before file upload area and the form fields are cleaning).
Now, if I choose another file > 500KB (or not pdf or jpg) the error message not appears.
The 'change', function in javascript is not invoked.

This is the javascript

```
    <script>
var inputElement = document.getElementById("fileToUpload")

inputElement.addEventListener('change', function(){
alert("QUI");
  var error = 0;
  var fileLimit = 500; // In kb
  var files = inputElement.files; 
  var fileSize = files[0].size; 
  var fileSizeInKB = (fileSize/1024); // this would be in kilobytes defaults to bytes
  var fileName = inputElement.value;
  idxDot = fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
  extFile = fileName.substr(idxDot, fileName.length).toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("filenamecheck").innerHTML = inputElement.value; 

  if (extFile=="jpg" || extFile=="pdf"){
     console.log("Type ok");
  } else {
     error = 1;
     document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Solo file .pdf o .jpg";
     document.getElementById("fileToUpload").value = "";
  }
  if (error == 0) {
  if(fileSizeInKB < fileLimit) {
     console.log("Size ok");
  } else {
     console.log("Size not ok");
     document.getElementById("error").innerHTML =  "Massima grandezza file: " + fileLimit + "KB";
     document.getElementById("fileToUpload").value = "";
  }
}
})
</script>
```

This the file upload area

```
 <div class="file-uploader">
    <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file" accept=".pdf,.jpg"/>
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
        <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>Clicca per scegliere il file     
          <span name="filenamecheck" id="filenamecheck">test</span>

    </label>
    <p id="error" style="color: #c00000"></p>
</div>
```

Someone can help me?

UPDATE: The correct URL is https://www.mamafrica.it/26964-2/

**UPDATE SOLVE** 
I have found a solution for my problem!!
First time, I have insert the javascript code after the end of form tag and the refresh work only on elements inside of form tag.
Using a wordpress hook (in function.php) i have insert the javascrip code immediatly after the input tag, inside of the form tag, in this way, the form refresh, reload also the javascript.
Thank you all!

Regards, 
Marco

Comment: If the form changes and the `<input>` is removed and re-created, you will have to add the event handler again.

Comment: I imagined it, but how can I do it?
The javascript code is always present on the page, even after the payment method switch.
(i am not very expert of javasript)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE
I have found a solution for my problem!! 
First time, I have insert the javascript code after the end of form tag and the refresh work only on elements inside of form tag. Using a wordpress hook (in function.php) i have insert the javascrip code immediatly after the input tag, inside of the form tag, in this way, the form refresh, reload also the javascript.

Thank you all!

Comment: Happy to read that, I guess that last posted comment gave you a hint.
"You might need to refresh the page at a point or part of it to be able to achieve what you are looking for."


Feel free to up-vote me in an effort to continue helping others.

 
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are using:
inputElement.addEventListener

That might be only triggered once.

You might use something in a form as simple as:
 onSubmit="return MyFunctionName"

That is being used in form validation for years.

I hope this helps,
Ramon

Comment: I can try, but the form is a part of givewp plugin and I don't know if it could cause problems

Comment: That's why I rather use my own webserver, gives you control of all the conditions.
But do not get discouraged. 
You can also attempt to load something on the submit button onclick like this page explains:<br>
https://html.form.guide/snippets/html-submit-button-onclick-code.html<br>

Best of lucks

Comment: Unfortunatlly, the onClick is not ok for my scope, because I need start the function, every time I load new file with <input type="file>

Comment: I check on the page https://www.mamafrica.it/26964-2/

Noticed when you change the method of payment, the page is no longer able to show the file you are attempting to upload.Could be related.

You might need to refresh the page at a point or part of it to be able to achieve what you are looking for.

Not sure what can be done with the previously mentioned script limitations.

Best of lucks